# How to make auto deselecting tableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view

and when I click the cell everything is fine

however, when I remove my fingers from the phone, the cell stays selected

how can I make it become deselected when the user stops touching the given cell and does not touch another cell

Comment: stays selected meaning your cell in blue color stays?

Answer (score 1):

Simple :

In this method : `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UIActionSheet *photoPicker ;

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

  }
```

Comment: This should work . I've checked in IOS7 as well . check your code with the complete UItableView Delegates .

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the style in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or change the cell in `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` and change back in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.
For example

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // ...
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue; // or an other style
    // ...
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // ...
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: this does not work - the cell does not show indication of being selected, i do want to display the selection, but i want the selection to go away, when user stops touching the tableview alltogether

Comment: I haven't tried this in iOS7, but on 6.1 it is running as you described. I touch the cell, it shows up blue. I release the touch (touch up) and the selection goes away

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in the UITableView delegate.

```
   -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: this does not work - it removes the indication the cell was ever selected - i do want to show the cell was selected, but the second the user takes his finger off of the cell, i want it deselected

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to handle the touch events?

For example: Add a UITapGestureRecognizer, detect which cell is being touched by using the `-(CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view` method. Mark the cell as selected when the touch begins and mark as deselected when the touch ends.

Answer (score 0):

Have you assigned delegate to UITableView?

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

That is the reason why you experience this

> this does not work - the cell does not show indication of being
>   selected

Answer (score 0):

In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, set the selected property of the cell to `NO` using the method `setSelected:animated:`.

E.g.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
}
```

**NOTE:**

Setting the cell's selected property = NO and animated = YES with the above method will cause the separator to disappear. The only way I've found to circumvent this is to set animated = NO but, if I find another way I will update my answer.